# AngularJS authentication not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, go

I'm trying to add authentication to my golang/angular app. the backend authentication works fine and logs that the user has logged in but the angular part is not working as expected, it doesn't set the username as when it successfully logs in and changes page, the username is not set.

**app.js**

```
blog.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, authService){ 
      $scope.login = function({
          authService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response, status){
              if(status == 200){
                  authService.setCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                  $window.location.href="/";
              } else {
                   $scope.invalidLogin = true;
              }
          });
      };
});

blog.factory('authService', function(username, password, callback){
    var service = {};
    var username = "";

    $http.post('/login', {Username : username, Password: password}).
    success(function(response, status){
        service.setCredentials(username, password);
        callback(response, status);
    });

    service.setCredentials = function(username, password){
              username = username;
    };

    service.getCredentials = function(){
             return username;
    };
      return service;
});

blog.controller('NavCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, authService){
    $scope.isAuth = (authService.getCredentials() != "");
    console.log("username: " + authService.getCredentials());
    $scope.username = authService.getCredentials();
});
```

Comment: i am not sure about this , but when the status is 200 and you are setting the credentials you might not have access to your $scope, so they are ending up undefined, try to return the username from the backend, and access to it from response.username or response.token, or whatever you need there.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Tried it there but no success. response.username definitely got the username ok but once the page change happens the variables remain undefined.

Comment: just another thing i noticed now, try to change this 2 lines:
  service.setCredentials = function(username, password){
              this.username = username;
    };

    service.getCredentials = function(){
             return this.username;
    };

Comment: still no luck. One thing I'm noticing is that console.log("username" + authService.getCredentials()) is always showing undefined. Should that not be an empty string like I set in the blog.factory ?

Comment: Check if there's a confusion with "username" - you use it both as a function argument and as a local variable.

Comment: I changed it around so that to use $rootScope instead and that's got it working. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your authService doesn't have the Login method you're calling from your controller:

```
blog.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window, authService){ 
      $scope.login = function({
          // Well there's your problem!
          authService.Login($scope.username, $scope.password, function(response, status){
              if(status == 200){
                  authService.setCredentials($scope.username, $scope.password);
                  $window.location.href="/";
              } else {
                   $scope.invalidLogin = true;
              }
          });
      };
});
```

Instead, you need to define your Login method within your factory like so:

```
myApp.factory('authService', function(){
    var service = {};
    var username = "";

    service.setCredentials = function(loginUsername, password){
              username = loginUsername;
    };

    service.getCredentials = function(){
             return username;
    };    

    service.Login = function(loginUsername, password, callback){
        $http.post('/login', {Username : loginUsername, Password: password}).
        success(function(response, status){
            service.setCredentials(loginUsername, password);
            callback(response, status);
        });
    }

    return service;
});
```

Note that I've also changed the username function parameters to loginUsername as it was shadowing the variable you where trying to assign to. This was causing the username value to be undefined.